# How to use a generic object and key type as the key in a dictionary

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking to make a function that can filter through a generic array using any key on the object and return the unique items. However Typescript will allow me to use the `T[Key]` as an array but not as a key of a dictionary.

THIS CODE WORKS:

```
const unique = <T, Key extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: Key): T[] => {
  var uniqueArray: T[Key][] = []
  var distinct: T[] = []

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!uniqueArray.includes(array[i][key])) {
      distinct.push(array[i])
      uniqueArray.push(array[i][key])
    }
  }

  return distinct
}

export default unique
```

THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK:

```
const unique = <T, Key extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: Key): T[] => {
  var uniqueDict: {[T[Key]]: number} = {}
  var distinct: T[] = []

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!uniqueDict[array[i][key]]) {
      distinct.push(array[i])
      uniqueDict[array[i][key]] = 1
    }
  }

  return distinct
}

export default unique
```

The second code example gives an error of `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)` on the `var uniqueDict ...` line.

If I write the dictionary as `{[id: T[Key]]: number} = {}` it also gives an error of `An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)` on the `var uniqueDict ...` line.

Any help on how I get the dictionary version of the unique method working?

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code; I would probably change it to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/weBlEN) which just uses `Record<string, number>` instead of trying to make it `{[P in T[Key]]: number}` (which is how you'd write that type, but it's not worth it unless you have an important reason to do that over `Record<string, number>`).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That works for me, however how does it know that `array[I][key]` will be a string indefinitely? I guess all keys of an object can be assumed to be a string given they can be accessed as `obj['key']`? Is that why that works. I'm very new to typescript and I was trying to work with `Record` however I was using the `T[Key]` type instead of `string` and it wasn't happy there.

Comment: I constrained `T extends Record<K, string>` so the compiler knows that `array[i]` (which is of type `T`) has a property at `key` (which is of type `K`) will be assignable to `string`. I will explain more when I write up my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that this is not valid syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
const unique = <T, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): T[] => {  
  var uniqueDict: { [T[K]]: number } = {} // syntax error
```

The syntax `{ [xxx]: number }` denotes a type where `xxx` is a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) and so must correspond to a key-like value.  You can't use a *type* there at all, let alone the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) type `T[K]`.

The right way to write that is to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
const unique = <T, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): T[] => {
  var uniqueDict: { [P in T[K]]: number } = {}; // error!    
  //                      ~~~~ <-- T[K] isn't known to be keylike
```

That's equivalent to `Record<T[K], number>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

---

But you see there's still a problem; the compiler has no idea that `T[K]` is a keylike type.  After all, `T` is the type of the elements of the `array`, and `K` is the type of `key`, which must be a key of `T`.  So `T[K]` is the property at that key... but is that property itself a `string`?  Probably not, for arbitrary `T` and `K`.

So to fix that, we can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` so that the compiler knows that `T[K]` is assignable to `string`:

```
const unique = <T extends { [P in K]: string }, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): T[] => {
  var uniqueDict: { [P in T[K]]: number } = {}; // error!    
  //  ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- {} isn't known to be assignable to this type
```

By constraining `T` to `{[P in K]: string}` (equivalent to `Record<K, string>`), the error at `[P in T[K]]` has cleared up.

---

But we still have a problem: the compiler does not believe that it's valid to assign an  empty object to a variable whose type must have a property with every key of the type `T[K]`.  And the compiler has a point; that empty object has no such keys when you assign it.

At this point there are different ways to proceed.  You can just tell a small lie to the compiler and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the empty object has those keys:

```
var uniqueDict = {} as { [P in T[K]]: number }; // okay
```

Or you could instead give `uniqueDict` an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
var uniqueDict: { [k: string]: number } = {}; // okay
```

The type `{ [k: string]: number }` means an object with some arbitrary `string`-valued keys, and at every key that's present, the value is of type `number`.  This is good enough for the rest of your code to compiler.  Note that, by default, the compiler will let you read from any arbitrary `string` key and act as if a property definitely exists there:

```
uniqueDict.randomKey.toFixed(2); // no compiler error, but probably runtime error
```

As long as you're careful not to make such assumptions in your code, you'll be fine.  Otherwise, you could turn on [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) to be safer (but this is more annoying and will affect more than just this one piece of code), or you could explicitly add `undefined` to the possible property types of `uniqueDict`:

```
var uniqueDict: { [k: string]: number | undefined } = {}; // okay
```

---

But at this point the whole thing compiles, so we can stop.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBADzgXjgIgBYFMA2OxoDcokscAZmGAFxwDecA2ggLq2wBOAlhAOZwBfFPTjY8NdAEMARiDSDiwCJIC2WKAAdJILHADy3fnWBw44aPACuELgEdLu1AB4AKgBo4AaThYEMLBAAJlBwANZYAJ5g5HAuAHwAFJIcHJIRtC6MLB7h6V4AlBlZKHH0JqZwAPSVcABuyXDWdg4AIlwgMLQMjJmeLGxwEJYq0lgcgsJ0QtVwUBEQMJJIYxxgHOWm9eNN9lhtHV1MAApwPLGMfQNDI2MTqFOEVTUra1AAhBVwG0+mAH7-AMBn2BcCBTgAtODzn1TlAIAByeChCBgADuEDgMDAcFGYUiOC44W+M2BAD1IVCprCEUiUejMdjcZIoFAuLxlNIcLosZiMFwQjAIhosMSap9vls4IF+TAeAdzixhFlgN9KOMEpKuMIAAyPLVOODJVIRAB0XL4MAweoA1Nb8mUQVwYgk3jtWu0YIwjWlGFwWIxcv17cYQaZpbA5TATRpLFAMEkUj6-flvp83XsPV7ExFff7A4rUABGVOCb4CFWfDhYGCWDgY8OyiAdcrl4Ct5RqTTaXQAMS4CD0EF0IbMpCsNl2wlcPj8AWCIkYJzOfXYMG4fEEHm8vn8QRCuWisUS3rymWyeLynkKCpKDoqkvT+06C6XGN6-Vo11G4yE9wEjxmF4OA+CpRT+QEILgCFKSEfkaTCOkMR5JkWTZDkuQZXl+UxIURQlBpHw9AAmSYhGZF9TjfC4P0GYZvwUH4wFCNIK3vBoG0jIoCyYFhVTWOANQaLVUF1U4oMNbMzQCXhLRtO070+J0BNdCd3Q6LNjVzANIiDBTgQ4psoxjOME005MS1MQj1JPLT82EYsQXLT4nIqKsazrKUZUjFsVXbVR1C0HQ4D7BAXFRbER3MMh0ynFwZ13edulfLwBk4Hh+AELd4rnfdIkPeJTLSLickiWgry428R02AjVIzeVulCVd114K46NuAAfRogiwcgeCwQI7nof9GOYiIwKsqNUiCMAVE8SITSxEL+oSIj8mIT5JQM+UzyVXjPjVATNR1PVxJPKSLStU5bWDEslJdCaNKTPMdJYG7Q08iNDOjWN4xs8z3oev7noifp7JLFzTAhuA3NresvMMnyBCAA)

Comment: This is an amazing explanation thank you so much @jcalz! Really appreciate all the information and links!